# Splitting on specific characters after regex

Tags: r, regex, string, split

I have a string that looks something like this:

```
s = "discount rates of 5% to 10%, and growth rates of 2% to 3%"
```

I'd like to split the string based on the character that comes after the first range, so in this case it would be the comma after "10%". The output would look like this

```
s = c("discount rates of 5% to 10%", " and growth rates of 2% to 3%")
```

The regex function I am using to extract the ranges is:

```
(\\$*\\d*\\.\\d+[%x] (to|and) \\$*\\d*\\.\\d+[%x])
```

and it has been working well so far (some of the ranges end in "x" instead of "%"), but instead of splitting on that regex - I need to split on the character that comes directly after it. If it's easier, I can also just split on the nearest space, so that the output would look like this:

```
s = c("discount rates of 5% to 10%," "and growth rates of 2% to 3%")
```

The reason why I'd like to split on whatever comes *after* the regex is because I'd like to preserve both matches (here it's "5 to 10%" and "2% to 3%"), but place them in different strings.

Comment: how are you splitting on this regex right now?

Comment: @doviod I have been using strsplit(s, "(\\$*\\d*\\.\\d+[%x] (to|and) \\$*\\d*\\.\\d+[%x])")

Comment: Doesn't work for me at all...

Comment: Not sure why, but I think I've found a solution to my problem: x = regmatches(s, gregexpr("(\\$*\\d*\\.\\d+[%x]( to | and | - |-)\\$*\\d*\\.\\d+[%x])", s)) , and then I unlist x

Answer (score 1):

What's about this:

```
s1 <- "discount rates of 5% to 10%, and growth rates of 2% to 3%"
s2 <- "discount rates of 5% to 10x, and growth rates of 2% to 3%"
sub("\\s*,.*", "", s1) # first range
sub(sub("\\s*,.*", "", s1), "", s1) # second range
substring(sub(sub("\\s*,.*", "", s1), "", s1), 1, 1) # get first character in second range
### solution:
unlist(strsplit(s1, substring(sub(sub("\\s*,.*","", s1), "", s1), 1, 1))) # case 1
#[1] "discount rates of 5% to 10%"   " and growth rates of 2% to 3%"
unlist(strsplit(s2, substring(sub(sub("\\s*,.*","", s2), "", s2), 1, 1))) # case 2
#[1] "discount rates of 5% to 10x"   " and growth rates of 2% to 3%"
```

Comment: I should have been more specific - while this technically works, the strings I am using are much larger and I don't want to split on every comma / space, only those that appear after the ranges.

Answer (score 1):

My solution is probably quite roundabout, but it might be enough:

```
ss<-gsub("(\\d+[%x],)", "\\1XX",s)
s<-unlist(strsplit(ss, split="XX"))
```

This assumes that "XX" doesn't actually appear anywhere, so replace it with a sufficiently unlikely string (I also simplified the regex to assume that a number followed by a percent or x, followed by a comma will always be split on).